# Transforming a list of maps representing bands

Tags: scala

I have the following code, it takes a list of maps representing bands and transforms the band properties via the `pipeline_each` method.

As you can see in the code, I am dealing with a lot of `Option`s being returned when I modify the band data in the map - I am using an immutable map object and therefore need to return a new map each time the function is called.

I am also not happy about the type of the bands data structure being a `List[Map[String, Any]]` - particularly the `Any` part because I need to convert the values I get out of the maps to `String` types in order to modify them. I am stuck with this data structure though.

How can I make this code better, specifically addressing my concerns above?

```
    object Exercise {

  val bands: List[Map[String, Any]] = List(Map("name" -> "sunset rubdown", "country" -> "UK", "active" -> true),
  Map("name" -> "women", "country" -> "Germany", "active" -> false),
  Map("name" -> "a silver mt. zion", "country" -> "Spain", "active" -> true))


  def set_canada_as_country(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    Map("name" -> band.get("name").get, "country" -> "Canada", "active" -> band.get("active").get )
  }

  def strip_punctuation_from_name(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    Map("name" -> band.get("name").get.toString.replace(".", ""), "country" -> band.get("country").get, "active" -> band.get("active").get )
    //toString above is kinda gross and could cause a class cast exception
    //do I have to handle all the case matching on some/none for all the above calls to get?
  }

  def capitalize_names(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    Map("name" -> band.get("name").get.toString.toUpperCase, "country" -> band.get("country").get, "active" -> band.get("active").get )
    //same again - don't like the toString
  }


  def pipeline_each(data: List[Map[String, Any]], fnList: List[Map[String, Any] => Map[String, Any]]): List[Map[String, Any]] = {
    fnList.foldLeft(data) {(bandList, currFn) => bandList.map(currFn)}
  }

}
```

I execute the above code via the REPL like so:

```
Exercise.pipeline_each(Exercise.bands,
  List(
    Exercise.set_canada_as_country,
    Exercise.strip_punctuation_from_name,
    Exercise.capitalize_names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `map` on `Option` to more cleanly access the values.

```
  def set_canada_as_country(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    band.get("name").map( name => band.get("active").map(active => 
      Map("name" -> name, "country" -> "Canada", "active" -> active))
  }
```

At this point, you could reasonable change the resulting type to `Map[String, String]`.

Rather than using a list of functions, you might want to compose a new function using `andThen`:

```
Exercise.pipeline_each(Exercise.bands, Exercise.set_canada_as_country andThen
  Exercise.strip_punctuation_from_name andThen
  Exercise.capitalize_names)
```

That way you are only applying a single filtering function.

Comment: A couple of things - I don't see how it's reasonable to change the resulting type to Map[String, String]. Second thing - I probably don't want to hard-code the composed function because I may want to supply other functions that modify the bands later?

Comment: As I understood it, you used `Map[String,Any]` because `Option` kept cropping up, meaning you had to use `toString`. Also, you can compose functions however you want; `andThen` is a better composition method than `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your original data structure is bound to something generic like Map[String,Any], you can still convert it to something more workable by defining apply() and converting to a case class.  At that point, you can make use of a lot of built in Scala features that your fellow developers will thank you for using.

First, create a case class that reflects the data:

```
case class Band(name: Option[String]=None, country:Option[String]=None, active:Option[Boolean]=None) {}
```

Next, create an 'apply' method that converts the map.

```
object Band {
    def apply(input: Map[String,Any]) = {
        Band(
            name = Try(input.get("name").asInstanceOf[String]).toOption,
            country = Try(input.get("country").asInstanceOf[String]).toOption,
            active = Try(input.get("active").asInstanceOf[Boolean]).toOption
        )
    }
}
```

Now, you can use standard case class operations and comprehensions:

```
Exercise.bands.map(Band(_))
    .map{ band => band.copy(country=Some("Canada"))}
    .map{ band => band.copy(name=band.name.map(_.replace(".","")))}
    .map{ band => band.copy(name=band.name.map(_.toUpperCase))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala uses camelCaseNotation, not underscore_notation.

`List[Map[String, Any]]` is indeed too complex.  And `Any` should be avoided at all costs.  See what I did below.  Note that the band name is very important (cannot be an `Option`) and is different from the other fields.

`Option`s are necessary here since many values in the "database" might be missing.

As mentioned by Bob Dalgleish, your `pipeline_each` is unnecessary since you are just composing functions.

```
 object BandDatabase {
    type BandDatabase = Map[String, BandInfo]
    case class BandInfo(country: Option[String], active: Option[Boolean]) 

    val bands: BandDatabase = Map(
      "sunset rubdown" -> BandInfo(Some("UK"), Some(true)),
      "women" -> BandInfo(Some("Germany"), Some(false)),
      "a silver mt. zion" -> BandInfo(Some("Spain"), Some(true)),
      "fake band" -> BandInfo(None, None))

    def mapKeys[A, B, C](map: Map[A, B], f: A => C): Map[C, B] =
      map.toList.map { case ((a, b)) => (f(a), b) }.toMap

    def mapValues[A, B, C](map: Map[A, B], f: B => C): Map[A, C] =
      map.mapValues(f)

    def stripPunctuationFromBandName: BandDatabase => BandDatabase =
      mapKeys(_, (s: String) => s.replaceAll("[,.!;:]", ""))

    def capitalizeBandNames(bands: BandDatabase): BandDatabase =
      mapKeys(bands, (s: String) => s.toUpperCase())

    def setCountryForAll(bands: BandDatabase, country: Option[String]): BandDatabase =
      mapValues(bands, (bi: BandInfo) => BandInfo(country, bi.active))

    val clean: BandDatabase => BandDatabase =
      stripPunctuationFromBandName
        .andThen(capitalizeBandNames)
        .andThen(setCountryForAll(_, Some("Canada")))
  }
  import BandDatabase._

  println(clean(bands))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is update the value for one member of a map with a new value you can use the `updated` method and the rest of the fields will be automatically copied.

```
  def set_canada_as_country(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    band.updated("country","Canada")
  }
```

For the other two functions where you want to modify one value use `transform` and write a function that modifies the value.

```
  def strip_punctuation_from_name(band: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
    band.transform{ (key,value) =>
      key match {
        case "name" => value.toString.replace("."," ")
        case _ => value
      }
    }
  }
```

You could do `capitalize_names` in the same way and then you would have no options left.